# Combining if tests with -o option in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Cannot find anywhere documentation on `-o` in `if` conditional statement in bash. Please suggest documentation.

Comment: There is no "if conditional statement". `if` executes the body if the _command_ returns with a zero exit status. There is a `[` or `test` command, and it's documentation is [posix test](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) or [bash conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html).

Comment: Wherever you find that option, modify it and use multiple `test` constructs instead of that. Even the POSIX page recommends that i.e. `test expr1 -o expr2 ` should be replaced with `test expr1 || test expr2`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use if with two conditions in OR logical relation you can use code like this:

```
if [ $a -eq 3 ] || [ $b = "c" ]
```

for AND logical relation this must be

```
if [ $a -eq 3 ] && [ $b = "c" ]
```